# Difference between using tf.layers.dense and creating our own layers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to customize my layers using two different approaches:

The first one is to create my own layers using two functions as below (which is inspired by the codes of [PINNs](https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs/blob/master/appendix/continuous_time_inference%20(Burgers)/Burgers.py)):

```
def initialize_NN(layers):
    weights = []
    biases = []
    num_layers = len(layers)
    for l in range(0, num_layers - 1):
        initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        W = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=[layers[l], layers[l + 1]])) 
        b = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=[1, layers[l + 1]])) 
        weights.append(W)
        biases.append(b)
    return weights, biases

def neural_net(X, weights, biases):
    num_layers = len(weights) + 1
    H = X 
    for l in range(0, num_layers - 2):
        W = weights[l]
        b = biases[l]
        H = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b))
    W = weights[-1]
    b = biases[-1]
    Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b)
    return Y
```

And the second one, I'm using tf.layers.dense:

```
def neural_net(X, layers):
    num_layers = len(layers)
    H = X
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
    for i in range(num_layers - 2):
        last_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=H, units=20, activation=tf.nn.tanh, kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=initializer)
    pred = tf.layers.dense(inputs=H, units=1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=initializer)
    return pred
```

I expected to obtain the same result from these two approaches but the performance of the second one was much worse than the first one. Did I do something wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the number of units in the first approach is 20?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Yes I believe. in both approaches the shape of X is (2,1) and the size of layers are [2,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,1].